# How to stop an infinite thread in an application server

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, infinite-loop

i have a JSF web application deployed under glassfish in which i have two buttons.The first start a infinite thread and the second stop it.My problem is that i can not stop a running thread.I have searched for a solution on the net but in vain.it works in case i have a J2SE application but not with a J2EE application here is my code

```
package com.example.beans;

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;

public class MyBusinessClass {
    public static void myBusinessMethod() {
        /* this method takes a lot of time */
        int i = 1;
        while (i == 1) {
            String random = RandomStringUtils.random(3);

            System.out.println(random);

        }
    }
}   


package com.example.beans;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.example.core.RandomUtils;

public class MySimpleRunnableTask implements Runnable {
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySimpleRunnableTask.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyBusinessClass.myBusinessMethod();
    }
}


@ManagedBean(name = "MainView")
@SessionScoped
public class MainView {

    private static Thread myThread;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public String startSimpleThread() throws SecurityException,
                                             NoSuchMethodException,
                                             InterruptedException {

        MySimpleRunnableTask mySimpleRunnableTask = new MySimpleRunnableTask();
        myThread = new Thread(mySimpleRunnableTask);
        myThread.start();
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
    public String stopSimpleThread() throws SecurityException,
                                            NoSuchMethodException, 
                                            InterruptedException {
        myThread.interrupt();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have changed my code so you can understand really what's my problem

Comment: Is it permitted for JSF code to create threads at all?

Answer (score 0):

interrupt only sets the interrupt status in the thread to true. The thread needs to regularly pool the interrupt status flag to stop running:

```
public void run() {
    /* you will have to touch the code here */
    int i = 1;
    while (i == 1) {
        String random = RandomStringUtils.random(3);
        logger.info(random);
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // the thread has been interrupted. Stop running.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only way to properly stop a thread : ask him to stop. Without cooperation from the running thread, there is no clean way.

Comment: that's the problem i  want to stop it without touching my infinite loop code

Comment: As I said, no way. The only solution I see, which is really ugly, is to make the RandomStringUtils.random() or the logger.info() method throw a runtime exception once you need to stop your thread. Why don't you want to add the necessary two lines of code?

Comment: have a look at my post you will understand what's my problem is

Comment: I reformatted the code to make it readable. If I understand correctly, the infinite loop with the random string is not the real code executed by your business method. It's just that this business method takes a lot of time to return. Is that right? It doesn't change the solution, though. Inside the business method, you just have to check as regularly as possible if the current thread has been interrupted or not, and return from this method (normally or by throwing an InterruptedException, for example) as soon as the interrupt status is true.

Comment: yes that's it but a freind of mine gave me the solution which is very easy :) .Just use myThread.stop() even if it's depreacated. :) Thanks again

Comment: merci beaucoup pour ton aide :)